# How to get html rows where text boxes , select boxes values have been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, asp-classic

I have a web form having multiple rows in HTML table. When I click Submit, it's updating all the rows ( passing input values of all the rows to the stored procedure parameter ). 
All I want is to pass and update only those rows where input values are changed.

My HTMl Source:

```html
<html>


<head>
<title> Dashboard:</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
 var gAutoPrint = true; // Tells whether to automatically call the print function
 function printSpecial()
  {
   if (document.getElementById != null)
    {
    var html = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';
    if (document.getElementsByTagName != null)
     {
     var headTags = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
     if (headTags.length > 0)
      html += headTags[0].innerHTML;
     }

     html += '\n</HE>\n<BODY>\n';

    var printReadyElem = document.getElementById("printReady");

    if (printReadyElem != null)
     {
      html += printReadyElem.innerHTML;
     }
    else
     {
      alert("Could not find the printReady function");
      return;
     }
    html += '\n</BO>\n</HT>';

    var printWin = window.open("","printSpecial");
    printWin.document.open();
    printWin.document.write(html);
    printWin.document.close();
    if (gAutoPrint)
     printWin.print();
    }
   else
    {
     alert("The print ready feature is only available if you are using an browser. Please update your browswer.");
    }
  }
  
  function validate()
  {
      //alert('here');
      var elements = document.getElementById("frmDtls").elements ;
      var val = [] ;
      var flag = true;
      var x = -1;
      var y = 0;
        
      if(flag == true)
      {
          document.frmDtls.hfrom.value = 'Updt' ;
          document.frmDtls.method = "post" ;
        document.frmDtls.action = "samepage.asp" ;
          document.frmDtls.submit();
         // alert("Record has been Updated Successfully!");
           //window.location.href = window.location.href;
         // location.reload();
       
                             
      }
//      alert(flag);
  }  
</script>

</head>

<body background="Images/Notebook.jpg">


<div align="center">
  <center>


<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" align="center">
    <img border="0" src="Axalta Coating Systems Logo.jpg" width="1200" height="60"></td>
  </tr>
</table>





<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="center"><b>
    <font face="Times New Roman" size="4"> CYCLE TIMES and UNITS for UPDATING </font></b>&nbsp;
     </TD>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="printReady">
<div align="center" id="formdiv"><center>
<form id="frmDtls" name="frmDtls">
<!--<form id="frmDtls" name="frmDtls" target="MyFrame">-->
<iframe id="MyFrame" name="MyFrame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<input type="hidden" name="hfrom" value = "">

<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="70%" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="center"><b>
  <font face="Times New Roman" size="5">SELECTED DUAL CODE DETAILS  </font></b>&nbsp;</td>
 <td width="13%" align="Middle" valign = "Middle" bgcolor="#FFFF00">
  <input type="button" name='update' value = 'Update' onclick='validate();'>
 </TD>
 <td width="17%" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="Center">
  <b><font face="Times New Roman" size="2"> 
    LATEST POSTING DATE / TIME 2/13/2019 7:09:20 AM</font></b>&nbsp;     
 </TD> 
  </tr>
</table>


<table BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1"
style="font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: left; width:100%;">
  <tr align="center">
    <th><small><small><span style="color:darkgreen;font-weight:bold">Profile ID</small></small></th>
    <th><WIDTH="200"><small><small><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">DUAL CODE</small></small></th> 
 <th><small><span style="color:darkgreen;font-weight:bold">Description</small></th>
 <th><small><span style="color:darkgreen;font-weight:bold">R/D Material?</small></th>
 <th><small><small><span style="color:darkgreen;font-weight:bold">Process Step Name</small></small></th>
 <th><small><small><span style="color:darkgreen;font-weight:bold">Process Step Sequence</small></small></th>
 <th><small><small><span style="color:darkgreen;font-weight:bold">FROM Event Status</small></small></th>
 <th><small><small><span style="color:darkgreen;font-weight:bold">TO Event Status</small></small></th>
 <th><small><small><span style="color:darkblue;font-weight:bold">Current CYCLE TIME</small></small></th>
 <th><small><small><span style="color:darkred;font-weight:bold">Updated CYCLE TIME</small></small></th> 
 <th><small><small><span style="color:darkblue;font-weight:bold">Cycle Time Units</small></small></th>

 <th><small><small><span style="color:darkred;font-weight:bold">Updated Units</small></small></th>

 <th><small><small><span style="color:darkblue;font-weight:bold">Comments</small></small></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><input type="Hidden" name="l_enteredpartialdualcode"   value=""  > </td>
 <td><input type="Hidden" name="l_selecteddualcodes"   value="1026-FD195, 1143-01427"  > </td>
 <td><input type="Hidden" name="l_selectedprocessstepnames"   value=""  > </td>
 <td><input type="Hidden" name="l_selectedgbtindicato"   value="Both"  > </td>
 <td><input type="Hidden" name="l_multipledualcodess"   value=""  > </td>
  </tr> 
<TR align=center><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>1</B></TD><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>1026-FD195</B></TD><TD WIDTH=200 Height=3><small><small><B>1026-FD195 E500546 DARK GRAY WBPR</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=30 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>Load_Cycle</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>2</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>LDGS      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>LDGC      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><B>6</B></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B><Select name = 'DDSQ_1_2' font-size=1><option value = '1' >1</option><option value = '2' >2</option><option value = '3' >3</option><option value = '4' >4</option><option value = '5' >5</option><option value = '6' selected>6</option><option value = '7' >7</option><option value = '8' >8</option><option value = '9' >9</option><option value = '10' >10</option><option value = '11' >11</option><option value = '12' >12</option><option value = '13' >13</option><option value = '14' >14</option><option value = '15' >15</option><option value = '16' >16</option><option value = '17' >17</option><option value = '18' >18</option><option value = '19' >19</option><option value = '20' >20</option><option value = '21' >21</option><option value = '22' >22</option><option value = '23' >23</option><option value = '24' >24</option><option value = '-1' >Clear</option></Select></B></small></small></TD>
  <TD WIDTH=70 Height=3 nowrap><small><small><B>
Hours     </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD>
            <td WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B><input type="text" name="txt_1_2" value="test1" >
   </B></small></small></TD>
   
<TR align=center><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>1</B></TD><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>1026-FD195</B></TD><TD WIDTH=200 Height=3><small><small><B>1026-FD195 E500546 DARK GRAY WBPR</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=30 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>Test_Cycle</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>4</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>TSTS      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>TSTC      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><B>6</B></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B><Select name = 'DDSQ_1_4' font-size=1><option value = '1' >1</option><option value = '2' >2</option><option value = '3' >3</option><option value = '4' >4</option><option value = '5' >5</option><option value = '6' selected>6</option><option value = '7' >7</option><option value = '8' >8</option><option value = '9' >9</option><option value = '10' >10</option><option value = '11' >11</option><option value = '12' >12</option><option value = '13' >13</option><option value = '14' >14</option><option value = '15' >15</option><option value = '16' >16</option><option value = '17' >17</option><option value = '18' >18</option><option value = '19' >19</option><option value = '20' >20</option><option value = '21' >21</option><option value = '22' >22</option><option value = '23' >23</option><option value = '24' >24</option><option value = '-1' >Clear</option></Select></B></small></small></TD>
  <TD WIDTH=70 Height=3 nowrap><small><small><B>
Hours     </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD>
            <td WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B><input type="text" name="txt_1_4" value="" >
   </B></small></small></TD>
   
<TR align=center><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>1</B></TD><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>1026-FD195</B></TD><TD WIDTH=200 Height=3><small><small><B>1026-FD195 E500546 DARK GRAY WBPR</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=30 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>FILL_Cycle</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>6</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>FLGS      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>FLGC      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><B>4</B></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B><Select name = 'DDSQ_1_6' font-size=1><option value = '1' >1</option><option value = '2' >2</option><option value = '3' >3</option><option value = '4' selected>4</option><option value = '5' >5</option><option value = '6' >6</option><option value = '7' >7</option><option value = '8' >8</option><option value = '9' >9</option><option value = '10' >10</option><option value = '11' >11</option><option value = '12' >12</option><option value = '13' >13</option><option value = '14' >14</option><option value = '15' >15</option><option value = '16' >16</option><option value = '17' >17</option><option value = '18' >18</option><option value = '19' >19</option><option value = '20' >20</option><option value = '21' >21</option><option value = '22' >22</option><option value = '23' >23</option><option value = '24' >24</option><option value = '-1' >Clear</option></Select></B></small></small></TD>
  <TD WIDTH=70 Height=3 nowrap><small><small><B>
Hours     </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD>
            <td WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B><input type="text" name="txt_1_6" value="test1" >
   </B></small></small></TD>
   
<TR align=center><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>2</B></TD><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>1143-01427</B></TD><TD WIDTH=200 Height=3><small><small><B>1143-01427 E450552 TITANIUM SBPR</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=30 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>Load_Cycle</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>2</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>LDGS      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>LDGC      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><B>3</B></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B><Select name = 'DDSQ_2_2' font-size=1><option value = '1' >1</option><option value = '2' >2</option><option value = '3' selected>3</option><option value = '4' >4</option><option value = '5' >5</option><option value = '6' >6</option><option value = '7' >7</option><option value = '8' >8</option><option value = '9' >9</option><option value = '10' >10</option><option value = '11' >11</option><option value = '12' >12</option><option value = '13' >13</option><option value = '14' >14</option><option value = '15' >15</option><option value = '16' >16</option><option value = '17' >17</option><option value = '18' >18</option><option value = '19' >19</option><option value = '20' >20</option><option value = '21' >21</option><option value = '22' >22</option><option value = '23' >23</option><option value = '24' >24</option><option value = '-1' >Clear</option></Select></B></small></small></TD>
  <TD WIDTH=70 Height=3 nowrap><small><small><B>
Hours     </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD>
            <td WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B><input type="text" name="txt_2_2" value="" >
   </B></small></small></TD>
   
<TR align=center><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>2</B></TD><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>1143-01427</B></TD><TD WIDTH=200 Height=3><small><small><B>1143-01427 E450552 TITANIUM SBPR</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=30 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>Test_Cycle</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>4</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>TSTS      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>TSTC      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><B>6</B></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B><Select name = 'DDSQ_2_4' font-size=1><option value = '1' >1</option><option value = '2' >2</option><option value = '3' >3</option><option value = '4' >4</option><option value = '5' >5</option><option value = '6' selected>6</option><option value = '7' >7</option><option value = '8' >8</option><option value = '9' >9</option><option value = '10' >10</option><option value = '11' >11</option><option value = '12' >12</option><option value = '13' >13</option><option value = '14' >14</option><option value = '15' >15</option><option value = '16' >16</option><option value = '17' >17</option><option value = '18' >18</option><option value = '19' >19</option><option value = '20' >20</option><option value = '21' >21</option><option value = '22' >22</option><option value = '23' >23</option><option value = '24' >24</option><option value = '-1' >Clear</option></Select></B></small></small></TD>
  <TD WIDTH=70 Height=3 nowrap><small><small><B>
Hours     </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD>
            <td WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B><input type="text" name="txt_2_4" value="test" >
   </B></small></small></TD>
   
<TR align=center><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>2</B></TD><TD Width=90 Height=3 nowrap ><B>1143-01427</B></TD><TD WIDTH=200 Height=3><small><small><B>1143-01427 E450552 TITANIUM SBPR</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=30 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>FILL_Cycle</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B>6</B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>FLGS      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=90 Height=3><small><small><B>FLGC      </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><B>6</B></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B><Select name = 'DDSQ_2_6' font-size=1><option value = '1' >1</option><option value = '2' >2</option><option value = '3' >3</option><option value = '4' >4</option><option value = '5' >5</option><option value = '6' selected>6</option><option value = '7' >7</option><option value = '8' >8</option><option value = '9' >9</option><option value = '10' >10</option><option value = '11' >11</option><option value = '12' >12</option><option value = '13' >13</option><option value = '14' >14</option><option value = '15' >15</option><option value = '16' >16</option><option value = '17' >17</option><option value = '18' >18</option><option value = '19' >19</option><option value = '20' >20</option><option value = '21' >21</option><option value = '22' >22</option><option value = '23' >23</option><option value = '24' >24</option><option value = '-1' >Clear</option></Select></B></small></small></TD>
  <TD WIDTH=70 Height=3 nowrap><small><small><B>
Hours     </B></small></small></TD><TD WIDTH=70 Height=3><small><small><B></B></small></small></TD>
            <td WIDTH=100 Height=3><small><small><B><input type="text" name="txt_2_6" value="test2" >
   </B></small></small></TD>
   


</table>
</form>
</center>

</div>
</div>


<p><small><small><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
End of Report.</strong></small></small></p>

<p align="center"><strong><big><big>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</big></big></strong></p>


</body>
</html>
 Run code snippetExpand snippet
```

Template is here : [Web Page Template](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ej0yhE3kGrFqZsNG58E5d_xZOUc7vwJB/view?usp=sharing)

Currently I am trying to append all the row id's with ';' separated on textbox OnChange event in javascript and store it in variable and then pass only these id's to my sql query but I am not able to figure out how to do that.

Is there any way you guys can help me out with?.

My HTML :

```html
<input type="text" name="txt_<%=l_profileid %>_<%=l_processstepsequence%>" value="<%= l_comments%>" onfocus="this.oldvalue = this.value;" onchange="onChangeTest(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;" >
```

```js
function onChangeTest(textbox){
    alert("Value is " + textbox.value + "\n" + "Old Value is " + textbox.oldvalue  + "\n" + "Name is " + textbox.name);
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code?, what did you try?, what are you getting as a result from it?

Comment: I have simply used alert to check if I am getting row id's as expected. but can't figure how to append all id's and store in variable

Comment: Describing the code or linking to a copy in Drive is not helpful.  You should publish your relevant code in your question.  If you want to create a working sample in addition (codepen or the like), that can be an nice _addition_ to the code in the question.

Comment: Added the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, I think this should work.
but If you can add some code, or explain what do you want to do with the row IDs, I can help more

```js
function submitTable(){
    var rows_ids = [];
    $('#content-table .new-value').each(function(){
        var old_value = parseInt($(this).parent().find('.old-value').text());
        var new_value = parseInt($(this).find('input.desired-input').val());
        if(old_value !== new_value){
            rows_ids.push($(this).parent().attr('id'));
            // use this as you want, it containes the id for the changed rows.
            // you have the changes value in new_value, so you also can use it.
        }
    });
    console.log(rows_ids);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="content-table">
    <tr id="1">
        <td>STG</td>
        <td class="old-value">4</td>
        <td class="new-value"><input type="text" name="txt_1_2" value="4" class="desired-input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td>LDG</td>
        <td class="old-value">3</td>
        <td class="new-value"><input type="text" name="txt_2_5" value="3" class="desired-input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
        <td>FLG</td>
        <td class="old-value">6</td>
        <td class="new-value"><input type="text" name="txt_3_6" value="6" class="desired-input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
        <td>FLG</td>
        <td class="old-value">7</td>
        <td class="new-value"><input type="text" name="txt_4_3" value="7" class="desired-input"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="submitTable()">Submit</button>
```

**EDIT:**
if you mean that you want to store the old value in the same input you can use the `data-` attribute to do so... then the code should look like this

```
function submitTable(){
    var rows_ids = [];
    $('#content-table .desired-input').each(function(){
        var old_value = parseInt($(this).data('old-value'));
        var new_value = parseInt($(this).val());
        if(old_value !== new_value){
            rows_ids.push($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
            // use this as you want, it containes the id for the changed rows.
            // you have the changes value in new_value, so you also can use it.
        }
    });
    console.log(rows_ids);
}
```

and you need to add `data-old-value="..."` to your input

`<input type="text" name="" value="7" class="desired-input" data-old-value="7">`

**EDIT2:** based on your comment, you can use `.split` to split the name on `_` and then get the id that you want, for the name format that you mentioned it should be at index 1,,  the js code should look like

```
function submitTable(){
    var ids = [];
    $('#content-table .desired-input').each(function(){
        var old_value = parseInt($(this).data('old-value'));
        var new_value = parseInt($(this).val());
        if(old_value !== new_value){
            ids.push($(this).attr('name').split('_')[1]);
        }
    });
    console.log(ids);
}
```

Comment: Yes almost there but dynamically generated names of my select boxes and text boxes are combination of three things 'DDSQ_1_4' , 'DDSQ_1_2' , 'DDSQ_1_6' , 'DDSQ_2_4' and "txt_1_2" , "txt_1_4" and so on submit I simply want to allow update to those rows where there is some change ( either in select box or checkbox or both )

Comment: can't you add a class name for your select, input elements?

Comment: Yes, I did try your solution. I have added Class name to td and input but instead of getting id out of tr can I get from input. my Input has name="txt_1_4" which is dynamically generated from asp code. txt is hard coded , 1 is the id I want to catch and 4 is another parameter. so overall I want to capture 1.

Comment: @Narendra I updated the answer based on your comment, please check it

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
$( "input" ).change(function() { 
   //Set flag on input 
   $(this).addClass("changed");
});
```

With this you can get all rows where a class named "changed" is present....